# AJAX request abort on large query string Elixir Plug

Tags: ajax, elixir

I am sending 2 large query string in AJAX requests, which are basically, a Base64 encoding of a jpeg(s). When the Camera is not a high-resolution one, AJAX request doesn't abort.

At first, I thought its a Nginx issue, Because I was getting an error as `request entity too large` I resolved it, Then I made changes to my Plug as

```
  plug Plug.Parsers,
    parsers: [
      :urlencoded,
      {:multipart, length: 20_000_000},
      :json
      ],
    pass: ["*/*"],
    query_string_length: 1_000_000,
    json_decoder: Poison
```

After defining `query_string_length`, Now I am not getting any errors like above but ajax request still abort.

Base64 encoding string size is `546,591 bytes` or max.

I have tried to increase the AJAX request timeout to a very large timespan as well but it still fails. And I don't have any clue where the problem is right now.

How can we receive long strings in `Plug`?

Some of few answers on StackOverflow about this issue where people used AJAX and PHP, suggesting to change `post_max_size`, How can we do that in Elixir Plug?

Comment: Did you post it as 'mutipart' type?

Comment: no? why would it be multipart? Its a string only

Comment: If you post it as string ,you should change the length in `Plug.Parsers`.

Comment: PS, I don't find the `query_string_length` option in the plug project.

Comment: I am sending it as a string, bas64 Encoded string. Also.. There is an option of quer_string_length option

Comment: I am posting as string, And I have changed the length in Parser but it still not working

Comment: How did you change it? You should change the name `query_string_length: 1_000_000` to `length: 20_000_000`

Comment: Post your comment as answer I will accept it.

Comment: I think that works?

Comment: Yes it worked. :)

Comment: Hum, I think you should merge your two questions.

Comment: How? Can I do that?

Comment: Sry, I see the doc. There is `query_string_length` option. You don't need to merge the questions. I will explain more details.

Comment: Hey, I want to ensure one thing. Did you post your string using `url-encode`?

Comment: We are sending AJAX request with JSON data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166684/discussion-between-yonghao-hu-and-junaid-farooq).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are sending AJAX request with JSON data, you should put the length config of json in the plug.

```
  plug Plug.Parsers,
    parsers: [
      :urlencoded,
      {:multipart, length: 20_000_000},
      {:json, length: 80_000_000},
      ],
    pass: ["*/*"],
    json_decoder: Poison
```

I suppose you will not put the data in the query string of the post, so the `query_string_length` - the maximum allowed size for query strings is not needed.

---

---Original answer---

For plug version around `1.4.3` and have no `query_string_length` option.

When you post the data as string, you are using `Plug.Parsers`.

> If you are willing to process larger requests, please give a :length
>   to Plug.Parsers.

You should change the code `query_string_length: 1_000_000` to `length: 20_000_000`.